# Parse Cloud Code query causing "No such app" error

Tags: heroku, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I'm running Parse Server on heroku and my cloud code functions work except when I try to query.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('debuggingFn', function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query("Speech");
  query.equalTo("speechId", "s_1456277936842");
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      console.log('SUCCESS', results)
      response.success("Success", results);
    },
    error: function(a, b) {
      // ERROR CAUGHT HERE: 'Heroku | No such app'
      console.log('ERROR', a, b)
      response.error("Error");
    }
  });
});
```

Speech is a valid class and that speechId exists. I don't know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. My SERVER_URL config field in heroku had a typo in it. Fixed that and everything seems to work now :)